# How to Point a directory to open on Server IP address as URL on Apache Web Server?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, symfony1, webserver

I am using Latest Ubuntu Linux and Apache2 Web server. I have made my Home directory as a Root directory of the Web server. Here I put multiple websites in different folders like

```
home/site1/
home/site2/
```

And they load on Browser like this

```
http://123.456.789.102/site1
http://123.456.789.102/site2
```

So now what I want to do is, I have one more directory as

```
home/mainsite/
```

And I want it to load when I directly use this URL in browser

```
http://123.456.789.102
```

Other thing about this site is, it is built using Symfony framework. So after configuration, the site will load using this URL

```
http://123.456.789.102/web
```

So next I have to do some configuration to remove /web from URL

I am not good at configuring Apache server files. So if anyone can guide me out, that would be very helpful.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

this should solve your problem, you should not use your IP/site directory, instead point a domain to that directory
some basic configuration
for main domain
main.conf file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/ directory wit

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName MAINDOMAIN.COM
DocumentRoot /home/mainsite/web
ServerAlias www.MAINDOMAIN.COM
<Directory /home/mainsite>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

create a symlink to the site with this command

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/main.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/main.conf
```

for a subdomain
subdomain.conf at /etc/apache2/sites-available/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName SUB.DOMAIN.COM
DocumentRoot /home/site1
ServerAlias www.SUB.DOMAIN.COM
<Directory /home/site1>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

create a symlink for it.

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomain.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/subdomain.conf
```

and finally restart apache2

```
service apache2 restart
```

this are just basics, take a look at links below for more information
[Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com)
[Ubuntu 11.04 server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/index.html)
[Apache2 guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/)

---

*edited after the comment of olivierw, thanks*
hope it helped

Comment: And if you use Symfony framework for the main site, it is best to set the `web` directory as the root directory for apache with `DocumentRoot /home/mainSite/web`...

Answer (score 0):

You may use an alias here:

```
Alias /site1 "/home/site1"

<Directory "/home/site1">
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```